# i am workig on a hotel management system which has 1 driver class and two other clsses Hotel and roomtype

Tags: java

I am workig on a hotel management system which has 1 driver class and two other classes, Hotel and roomtype.
I need to add objects of room type which should be added to hotel object where it belongs.

[image]

Comment: Note that you can add code in your question and try explaining your code and what is wrong with it to get answers. I mean explain your question

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Initialising the Program:
Initialising the program requires the following steps:
1. Create an array that can store 4 Hotel objects
2. Create a new Hotel for each of the hotels listed in Table 1 on page 3, defining their attribute values. Place each of these hotels into an element of the array from the previous step.
3. Create new RoomType objects for each entry in Table 2 on page 4. Each RoomType object should be added to the Hotel object to which it belongs.

Comment: i am having issues adding Roomtype objects to the specific hotel objects

Answer (score 0):

Add an Object to your class Hotel like this

```
    Room room = new Room();
```

Then in the constructor set the room to your Hotel.

```
    Public Hotel(Room room){
            this.room = room;
    }
```

There is more than one room in a Hotel usually. Another way to add rooms to a hotel is to write a method wich fills a list within hotel.

```
    Public Class Hotel(){
            List<Room> rooms = new ArrayList<Room>();

            public void addRoom(Room room){
                    room.add(room);
            }
    }
```